# Some properties of subsequential limit set for any sequence whose distance of consecutive terms goes zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, metric-spaces

This problem, which is present as 3.2:6 on page 27 in "Supplements to the Exercises in Chapter 1-7 of Walter Rudin's Principles of Mathematical analysis" by Prof. George M. Bergman, states as follows,

In (a)-(g) below, let $X$ be a metric space, $(s_{n})$ a sequence in $X$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} d(s_{n}, s_{n+1}) = 0$ and $E$ the subsequential limit set of $(s_{n})$.

(a) Show that if $X = \mathbb{R}$, then $E$ is connected.

(b) Show that for every $\epsilon > 0$, all but finitely many natural numbers $n$ have the property that there exists $p \in E$ with $d(s_{n}, p) < \epsilon$.

(c) Show that if $X$ is compact, then $E$ is connected.

(d) Give an example where $X = \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $E$ is not connected.

(e) Show that if $X = \mathbb{R}^{k}$ and $E$ is not connected, then it contains an unbounded connected subset.

(f) Show that if $X = \mathbb{R}^{k}$ and $(s_{n})$ is not convergent, then $E$ is perfect.

(g) Show that if $X$ is a connected compact metric space, then there exists a sequence  $(s_{n})$ with $\lim_{n \to \infty} d(s_{n}, s_{n+1}) = 0$ whose subsequential limit set is all of $X$.

I am struggling with (b) for weeks and cannot find a solution. The following is my current progress about (b).

First, $E$ should not be empty, otherwise this assertion does not hold. Now assume $E$ is not empty, and the statement does not hold, then there exists a $t > 0$ such that, by letting $L = \{n \mid d(s_{n},p) \geq t \text{ for all }p \in E\}$, $L$ is infinite. Given any $u,v$ with $0 < u < v < t$, let $U = \{n \mid d(s_{n},p) \leq u\text{ for some }p \in E\}$ and $V = \{n \mid d(s_{n},p) \geq v \text{ for all }p \in E\}$, then both $U$ and $V$ are infinite.

If there exist only finitely many terms such that $u < d(s_{n},p) < v$ for all $p \in E$ (such $s_{n}$ is in $(U\cup V)^{c}$), then there is a subsequence $(s_{n_{i}})$ such that $n_{i} \in V$ and $n_{i} + 1 \in U$, and $d(s_{n_{i}},s_{n_{i}+1}) \geq v - u$, a contradiction. Hence there exists a infinite set $V_{u} = \{n \mid u \leq d(s_{n},p) < v\text{ for all }p \in E\}$ and both $U$ and $V$ intersect $V_{u}$ infinitely many times. Since $\lim d(s_{n},s_{n+1}) = 0$, there exists a subset of $V_{u}$ such that $\lim d(s_{n_{i}},E) = u$ as the index goes infinity, and such $u$ is uniquely determined.

I stuck here and could not find a contradiction, since no further analysis I can do about this subsequence $(s_{n_{i}})$ whose distance is almost a constant to $E$. Could anyone help me out with this part and I appreciate your suggestions.

P.S., If possible, can anyone also give me some clues about part (d) please

Comment: In summary, based on @Mark Saving's counterexample,  parts (b), (e), and (f) does not hold, but under the condition that $X$ is compact, part (b) holds and part (c) turns out to be true via part (b). Part (g) holds by using the chain connected set property and the fact that compact set is separable (enumerate any countable dense set and fill finitely many points between the consecutive points to satisfy the condition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having a problem with (b) because (b) is not true.

Consider $s_n = \sqrt{n}$. Then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} d(s_n, s_{n + 1}) = 0$ (since $d(s_n, s_{n + 1}) = \sqrt{n + 1} - \sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} + \sqrt{n + 1}}$). But $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} s_n = \infty$, so $E = \emptyset$. Therefore, (b) is false.

For (d), consider the family of elipses, indexed by $n$, which satisfy $x^2 + \frac{y^2}{n^2} = 1$. Traverse each elipse one at a time, and with each traversal, make the maximum step size half the maximum step size of traversing the previous elipse. Then the only limit points are $(\pm 1, 0)$.

Incidentally, the (d) example is also another counterexample to (b).

Comment: Thanks for your answering, for part (b), in my proof I also realized it does not hold if the sub-sequential limit set is empty. Do you have any clue whether the statement holds or not when the sub-sequential limit set is not empty?

Comment: Sorry but I am still digesting your counterexample. Could you please explain it in detail about the traverse? From my understanding is that we have a bunch of vertical lines that transverse this family of ellipses, and I do not follow the sentence “make the maximum step size half the maximum step size...”

Comment: @hmeng1 First, we discretely "walk around" the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ (perhaps we go $(1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (0, -1)$). Then, we "walk around" the ellipse $x^2 + y^2/4 = 1$ in the same way, but taking smaller "steps" each time. Then, we do the same thing for $x^2 + y^2/9 = 1$.

Comment: Wait, seems your counterexample also disproves the part (e), right?